# How to get user selected filters before applying calculations in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to allow for users to select filters before running any calculations on the data and generating an output - ideally in a dashboard type environment.

For example:

1. User selects the following filters

`Month = 2024-01`

`Country = United States`

`Product = Shoes`

2. User's selections filter the original data source

`month_mask = df['month'] == '2024-01'`

`country_mask = df['country'] = 'United States'`

`product_mask = 'Shoes'`

`sub_df = df[month_mask & country_mask & product_mask]`

3. Subset goes through calculations

`sub_df = sub_df.groupby('SKU').mean()[['price', 'quantity]]`

`sub_df['total price'] = sub_df['price'] * sub_df['quantity']`

4. Output to user in appropriate visual such as bar chart or line graph

I'm struggling to make the transition between step 1 and 2 automated. Currently, I have a process where I have users input an entry on an excel template as an input file and each new row is run through the code, but is there a way to make this more on demand similar to a Power BI dashboard? It's a must that the filters are applied before the calculations as the opposite would generate different outputs.

Comment: You can google and take a look at dash & plotly